# Ubuntu 11.10 Software center struck at "Applying Changes" and Update Manager won't proceed because of an Installation Error

Tags: software-center, update-manager

I have an issue with this application called "Sandboxgamemaker". First of all, it did not install properly as the Software Center was struck at "Applying Changes". When I opened the Update Manager in order to recover, it warned me to not to proceed without a 'partial update', which is of-course for the improperly installed Sandboxgamemaker app.

As I did, the Update Manager stopped responding and I thought of doing it manually. So I used the below command

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Both in the Update Manager and in the terminal, despite trying for all the given options of:

```
replace PlatinumArtsSandbox2.6.1/bin/jpeg.dll? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:
```

I'm struck here, as shown below:

```
Processing triggers for python-central ...
Setting up sandboxgamemaker (2.6.1+dfsg-7) ...
Cleaned old data
--2012-07-25 18:05:21--  http:// sandboxgamemaker. com/sandbox/PlatinumArtsSandbox2.6.1Multiplatform.zip
Resolving sandboxgamemaker.com... 173.236.241.215
Connecting to sandboxgamemaker.com|173.236.241.215|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://  www.sandboxgamemaker. com/sandbox/PlatinumArtsSandbox2.6.1Multiplatform.zip [following]
--2012-07-25 18:05:23--  http:// www. sandboxgamemaker. com/ sandbox/PlatinumArtsSandbox2.6.1Multiplatform.zip
Resolving www. sandboxgamemaker. com... 173.236.241.215
Reusing existing connection to sandboxgamemaker.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.

replace PlatinumArtsSandbox2.6.1/bin/jpeg.dll? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could try `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` and fix any missing dependencies on your computron. :) If that doesn't work, try  removing it and reinstalling. See if you get the same issue.

Comment: Thank you very much @UrFriendlyVirus. I did the --fix-missing thing, it updated few things, but in the end all it showed me was                                         
> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear your problem is resolved @Sunit Prassad!

Comment: No no.. sadly, it didn't.. I tried your suggestion, after few steps of execution, it again asked me to run the  "sudo dpkg --configure -a" and that is what is my problem as I mentioned!! please look at the screen shots from the below link...
http://goo.gl/X1Mqk

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer.

First I used this code

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

when it completed its execution, I tried to force remove the faulty application by a simple

```
sudo dpkg -r –force-depends
```

and then finally

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and bingo problem solved!

Thank you very much @UrFriendlyVirus